# Freeze header row and columns in WPdatatables?

Tags: wordpress

I am using wpdatatable paid plugin if wordpress.
so in frontend it is showing tables with data. i want to freeze header row and first column of the table.

Answer (score 0):

For freezing the column you'll need to add a css class to the column settings. In the example below i have used the name 'Firstcol'

You will need to adjust the width, left and margin top in accordance to your table.

```
table.wpDataTable td.Firstcol {   color:#ffffff;    font-weight: bold; position: absolute;   width: 10.5em;   left: 0em;   border-top-width: 1px;   /*only relevant for first row*/   margin-top: -0.75px; }
```